# Three.js - Align cube to a grid

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using `GridHelper` to make a grid and I would like to place a cube directly on top of a grid's tile. Here is my current implementation, which puts a cube on a grid, but it not directly aligned with a tile.

```js
// cubes
cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xfeb74c } );
var voxel1 = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, cubeMaterial );
scene.add(voxel1); 
  
// grid
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 1000, 20 );
console.log(gridHelper);    
scene.add( gridHelper );
```

[Grid with Box not align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iy03.png)

How would i go about making the box align with the grid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate your geometry after it is created, like so:

```
cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
cubeGeo.translate( 25, 0, 25 );
```

If you add additional cubes, you can reuse the same geometry, and set the mesh's position:

```
voxel.position.set( x, y, z );
```

three.js r.87